# Whera are the Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) relese notes published?

Tags: 21.10, release-notes

Did the final Impish Indri release notes get published somewhere? There's a closed discussion in discourse, but nothing shows up in search on the wiki, and the obvious link (following the pattern for previous releases) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImpishIndri/ReleaseNotes doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

The release notes for Impish are redirected from mentioned wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImpishIndri/ReleaseNotes to Ubuntu Discourse/Community

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951

Comment: A link to the release notes is shown in the update process in Software Updater.